# Element position is wrong in some mobiles

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-website, webflow

I've built a website on Webflow, but hoping you can help here.

For some reason, certain couple of elements are shown way below their original position in specific iPhone devices (eg. iPhone XS, safari).

Here’s how it should look:

[image]

And here’s how it looks in some iPhones:

[image]

(it’s actually there on top of the companies logos).

[Live site is here](https://guyman.com)

I’m trying to figure this out but simply can’t.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [add your code directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

firstly remove any margins and padding from below "Some of our creations" and than your collaborations which are moving will stop in small screen, if you want to run them do the coding again in media query. Other things are good